# YouTube Android API для проигрывания видео

Tags: android, youtube-android-api

Добрый день! Использую YouTube Android API для воспроизведения видео в своем приложении. Суть проблемы заключается в следующем. Когда запускаю приложение на эмуляторе/телефоне - видео начинает сразу же воспроизводиться. Я понимаю, какая часть кода за это отвечает, но я не понимаю как прописать код, чтобы при запуске приложения видео стартовало только при нажатии на YouTubePlayerView. 
на всякий случай кидаю код, может подскажете толковое что-нибудь.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements OnInitializedListener {
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
    private static final String VIDEO_ID = "ERRypaEEsC8";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Log.d("logs", "onInitializationFailure");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это потому что вы используете `player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID)`. Согласно [документации](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)), этот метод загружает и воспроизводит видео.

Попробуйте так:  `player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID)`

Метод `cueVideo()` загружает видео, но [не начинает проигрывать](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#cueVideo(java.lang.String)) до вызова `play()` (вызывается, если на кнопку `>` нажать)

Comment: Да, точно! То, что мне нужно. Спасибо :)